# Windows Phone 7 sniffer

Tags: windows-phone-7, sniffing, sniffer

Does any know some good http (at least) sniffer which works under Windows Phone 7 OS?
Currently I use wireshark/fiddler + windows phone 7 emulator for testing, but anyway I want to test my app using real phone + some win 7 phone sniffer too.
I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Why? Are you seeing behaviour on a real device which indicates different network traffic?

Comment: I'm just curious :)
Btw from time to time I face with strange exception. It occures *only* when I use fiddler. So it will be much better to have some extra sniffing soft.

Comment: I mean this exception occured *only* when I use consume asmx web service by WP7 application while Fiddler is running.
*There was no endpoint listening at http://site.com/service.asmx that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.*
When I turn Fiddler off, then this error dissapears. So from time to time I want test app at device, not in emulator. So now I'm searching for WP7 sniffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Fiddler with your device also.

Mike Ormond demonstrates here.

[More Monitoring Web Requests on Windows Phone](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/14/more-monitoring-web-request-on-windows-phone-7.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The current Windows Phone platform SDK does not expose access to the network stack or the radio interface at all, so in the current incarnation there is no way to create a sniffer for the platform.

Comment: Thanks. That's sad but at least bad news are much better than no news at all.