# Testing WCF Services

Tags: c#, wcf

I have two WCF services. I know that one of them works and one of them doesn't My problem is I'm calling them from WP7 emulator and nothing is appearing in Fiddler (even for the one that's working, and I've tried everything to get stuff working).

Regardless, what is a recommended way to test POST requests to a WCF service?

Answer (score 0):

I always try to develop using TDD. This implies that I create a unit test project, and use unit tests to test my services.

Comment: I am using TDD. My problem is, I'm getting some communication error on POST requests. Because I can't get FIDDLER to work, I'm trying to see if anyone has any other ideas.

Comment: "Create a failing unit test". Also, look in the Fiddler FAQ for how to set up Fiddler to work on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking two slightly different questions so I'll answer to them separately.
So first of all you have some troubles with sniffing WP7 emulator traffic using fiddler. Sometimes fiddler rejects to sniff WiFi traffic when you use WP7 emulator. In my case fiddler started sniffing only when I turn off WiFi and use Ethernet cable (and data cable for WP7 device of course). So disabling wifi is one option. And second option is reconfiguring fiddler. Please check this topic (it's about configuring fiddler for work with WP7): [Windows Phone 7 sniffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441973/windows-phone-7-sniffer)

So your second question about tools. I use (for a pretty long time) one really useful tool named [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/). Just install it, create new project and have a fun. Please note that you should enter path to wsdl when creating new project with soapUI. It will look like this: myservicename.svc?wsdl

I hope this will help you. Anyway please ask questions if you have some.

Comment: btw, free version of soaupUI has all functionality that need for common tasks. And also it tightly coupled with another great (and free) tool: loadUI. I use it for load testing of wcf services.